# Storing Dynamic data in relational database (SQL Server 2014)

Tags: sql-server

Hi my data model contains some static type properties and one dynamic type property. That property could contain array, string, integer, range. Now, simple solution would be create separate column for each one, but problem with that approach is, I will end up with few of optional columns as only one of the type is present at a time(rest of the columns will be null).

My preferred approach is to save it in one field (preferable text or json) and parses the data according to the type. Well parsing has its cost but I still feel this is better approach, but I am no expert in DB, so I am looking for your opinions. 
Thanks

Comment: Is this data going to be used as a predicate for searching, in calculations etc? What is the context of the dynamic data exactly?

Comment: Do you know the data type while inserting into the table? You could store the value as a varchar and then do the casts in a case statement accordingly to it's datatype, stored in another column as a varchar as well.

Comment: @George.Palacios, they won’t be used as predicate for searching but the data will be used for calculation. Speaking of context, this dynamic data are basically criteria for calculating discount for different type of fares

Comment: @PawełKucharski yea I know data type while inserting data and that’s exactly what I am thinking. I think performance wise varchar will be faster than xml or json, but just not sure if its better option oppose to other option that I mentioned.

Comment: I would go with Varchar - then have a front end perform the calculation.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are looking for an **Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV)** data model design.  Aaron Bertrand has a [great post on this](https://sqlblog.org/2009/11/19/what-is-so-bad-about-eav-anyway) which I suggest you look through and see if a similar approach will fit your needs.

As a DBA, I have a deep-seeded hatred for this approach, but sometimes it makes the most sense for the situation at hand.

If you can convince whoever controls the budget to upgrade to SQL Server 2016, there are some new features that take advantage of [JSON data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/json/json-data-sql-server), which can give you even more flexibility.

Comment: Or just "upgrade" to postgres :)

Answer (score 0):

Use XML column type and XML indexes on that column.

Comment: I was thinking about using varchar type as I heard bad stuff about xml type , specially regarding performance (by the way, I never used xml type, so please forgive my ignorance)

Comment: What kind of bad stuff?